# sed: What's wrong with this replace command?

Tags: regex, sed, replace

I'm trying to replace the `package` line in a java file using this sed command:

```
sed -i "s/package org\.objectweb\.asm[.\w]*;/package $package;/" FILE
```

but it doesn't work as expected. What's wrong with this replace command?

Comment: `[.\w]` matches a character that is either a dot, a backslash, or a w, which is almost certainly not what you want; what do you want to match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to match what `\w` would match, plus a dot. `\w` doesn't work like that inside a `[]` character set. Try `[.a-zA-Z0-9_]` instead:

```
sed -i "s/package org\.objectweb\.asm[.a-zA-Z0-9_]*;/package $package;/" FILE
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `sed` does not support a `\w` Perl-like [shorthand character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) that matches digits, letters or underscores.

In the POSIX pattern, instead of `\w`, you would use `[_[:alnum:]]` where `[:alnum:]` is a [**POSIX character class**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html#class) matching any alphanumeric chars. And `[._[:alnum:]]` seems to be what you meant to use here:

```
sed -i "s/package org\.objectweb\.asm[._[:alnum:]]*;/package $package;/" FILE
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

However, judging by your string structure, you may just match any chars but `;` with a negated bracket expression `[^;]`:

```
sed -i "s/package org\.objectweb\.asm[^;]*;/package $package;/" FILE
                                     ^^^^^
```